xfig reduces font size when exporting
xfig (through fig2dev) reduces font size when exporting by a factor of 1.3229.
I first thought this might be related to the particular point size adopted in xfig (1/80 inch in xfig/fig2dev, as opposed to 1/72 inch), but that's not the case (80/72 = 1.1111).
Actually, the -F option is not recognized by fig2dev when exporting to png, and one gets the error
Argument -F unknown to png driver.

Opening xfig with the -correct_font_size option does not have any effect either (as expected from fig2dev not recognizing the corresponding option -F).
As a MRE, this fig file, which just contains a single letter "A"
#FIG 3.2  Produced by xfig version 3.2.6a
Landscape
Center
Metric
A4
100.00
Single
-2
1200 2
4 0 0 50 -1 18 132 0.0000 4 1620 1605 10575 7335 A\001

is converted to
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Creator: fig2dev Version 3.2.6a -->
<!-- CreationDate: 2024-04-02 11:00:16 -->
<!-- Magnification: 1.05 -->
<svg    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="106pt" height="104pt"
    viewBox="10560 5700 1676 1650">
<g fill="none">
<!-- Text -->
<text xml:space="preserve" x="10575" y="7335" fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" font-size="1584" text-anchor="start">A</text>
</g>
</svg>

by the command
fig2dev -L svg test_A.fig test_A.svg

The font size is indicated in pt in the fig file (132), but not in the svg file (1584, I don't know which units are used there).
If I open the svg file with inkscape, the font size shows as 99.78302765 (132 / 99.78302765  = 1.3229).
I suspect that the discrepancy might be due to a point/pixel confusion, since the ratio between the two is close to the shrinking ratio observed, but not identical (one point is the equivalent of 1.333 pixels).
Does anyone know what could be the origin of this font size discrepancy, and how to fix it?

It would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal working example. For instance, a fig file attached and the outcome.

Thank you @tkl, I edited my question

Is the issue related to LaTeX in some way, or is it just about converting xfig to svg?

It's mostly a question about xfig. I apologize if this is not the best place to ask, but I think this is the only SE community with a xfig tag.
